# Demonstration of $\lim_{x\to 1 } \sqrt x = 1$

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to 1 } \sqrt x = 1$$

I have to demonstrate that limit with $ \epsilon - \delta $ definition, I took

$ | \sqrt x -1| = \frac{x-1}{ \sqrt x +1} < \epsilon $

If I take $ \delta = 1 $ then:

1> $ \frac{1}{\sqrt x +1} > \frac{1}{\sqrt 2 +1}$

Then:

$\frac{|x-1|}{|\sqrt x +1|} < |x-1| *1< \epsilon$

Thus: $ \delta = min(1, \epsilon) $

I would be grateful to know if that answer is correct

Comment: Just "taking $\delta= min(1, \epsilon)$" is NOT a "demonstration or  proof!  What proof or demonstration did you use?

Comment: This is barley an answer. Could you show the whole proof?

Comment: I just added the details, if it is not clear I could add more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly we must require that $x\ge 0$ in order for $\sqrt{x}$ to be defined. Naturally, if $x$ is close enough to $1$ this isnt a problem. Also observe that $\sqrt{x}\ge 0$ and so $\sqrt{x}+1\ge 1$, $\forall x\ge 0$.

Then $\forall \varepsilon>0$, choose a $\delta>0$ such that $\delta\le\min\{\varepsilon, 1\}$.

Now, if $0<|x-1|<\delta$ then:

- Since $\delta\le 1$ we ensure that $x\ge 0$, and
- $|\sqrt{x}-1| = \left|\frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)(\sqrt{x}+1)}{\sqrt{x}+1}\right|= \left|\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{x}+1}\right|=\frac{|x-1|}{|\sqrt{x}+1|}\le\frac{|x-1|}{|1|}=|x-1|<\delta\le\varepsilon$.

Thus, $|\sqrt{x}-1|<\varepsilon$. This is the precise definition of $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\sqrt{x}=1$.  $\;\;\;\blacksquare$

This is my proof. Yours needs to be expanded on a great deal though; it is not a rigorous "proof" by any measure.  You need to flush it out.

Comment: Nice answer.  In your final sentence, I believe you were looking for the expression [flesh it out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/top-10-commonly-confused-words-vol-2).

Comment: haha. yeah.  I suppose so. Though I dont know how "fleshing" makes any more sense than "flushing".